# How to get the actual Hyperlink element inside the main document part using docx4j

Tags: xpath, docx4j

So I have a case where I need to be able to work on the actual Hyperlink element inside the body of the docx, not just the target URL or the internal/externality of the link.

As a possible additional wrinkle this hyperlink wasn't present in the docx when it was opened but instead was added by the docx4j-xhtmlImporter.

I've iterated the list of relationships here:  `wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart().getRelationships().getRelationship()`

And found the relationship ID of the hyperlink I want.  I'm trying to use an XPath query: `List<Object> results = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//w:hyperlink[@r:id='rId11']", false);`
But the list is empty.  I also thought that it might need a refresh because I added the hyperlink at runtime so I tried with the refreshXMLFirst parameter set to true.  On the off chance it wasn't a real node because it's an inner class of P, I also tried `getJAXBAssociationsForXPath` with the same parameters as above and that doesn't return anything.

Additionally, even XPath like `"//w:hyperlink"` fails to match anything.

I can see the hyperlinks in the XML if I unzip it after saving to a file, so I know the ID is right: `<w:hyperlink r:id="rId11">`

Is XPath the right way to find this?  If it is, what am I doing wrong?  If it's not, what should I be doing?

Thanks

Comment: A shot in the dark: You need to provide a mapping for the namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XPathHyperlinkTest.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/test/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/XPathHyperlinkTest.java) is a simple test case which works for me

You might be having problems because of JAXB, or possibly because of the specific way in which the binder is being set up in your case (do you start by opening an existing docx, or creating a new one?).  Which docx4j version are you using?

Which JAXB implementation are you using?  If its the Sun/Oracle implementation (the reference implementation, or the one included in their JDK/JRE), it might be this which is causing the problem, in which case you might try using MOXy instead.

An alternative to using XPath is to traverse the docx; see [finders/ClassFinder.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/finders/ClassFinder.java)

Comment: I'm on a slightly older docx4j, 3.2.2 with some custom patches due to the application environment I'm working in.  The test wasn't an appropriate case because my hyperlinks are created and added to the document after the initial loading.  So it seems like the JAXB issue and using the ClassFinder worked for me with minimal pain.

ClassFinder classFinder = new ClassFinder(P.Hyperlink.class);

Answer (score 0):

Try without namespace binding

```
List<Object> results = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath("//*:hyperlink[@*:id='rId11']", false);
```